# JLabel isn't moving

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel

I'm attempting to make a program that moves a label down and to the right of the frame but nothing is working, the while loop is being triggered so the code is running but the label wont move. Sorry I'm a beginner and don't really understand what's going on.

The code also uses the `Stopwatch` class shown below the `animation` code.

### `animation`

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class animation {

private JFrame frame;

boolean isMoving = false;
int labelX = 0;
int labelY = 0;
int x, y;
private final JButton button = new JButton("Start");
JLabel lblO = new JLabel("O");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                animation window = new animation();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public animation() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
     x = frame.getWidth();
     y = frame.getHeight();

    lblO.setBounds(0, 0, 15, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblO);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            button.setText("End");
            if(isMoving){

                movetheball();
            }
            else{
                isMoving = true;
            }
            }
    });
    button.setBounds(168, 219, 84, 31);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    }

public void movetheball(){
    StopWatch tim = new StopWatch();
    tim.start();
    while(isMoving){
        long time = tim.getElapsedtime();
        if(time>1){

            System.out.println("The Timer is Working");
            labelX+= 150;
            labelY += 150;
            lblO.setBounds(labelX,labelY,15,15);
            }
    }
}
}
```

### `Stopwatch`

```
    public class StopWatch {
private long elapsedTime;
private long startTime;
private boolean isRunning;

public StopWatch(){

}

public void start(){
    isRunning = true;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

public void stop(){
    isRunning = false;

}

public long getElapsedtime(){
    if(isRunning){
        long  endTime =System.currentTimeMillis();
        return elapsedTime + endTime - startTime;

    }
    else{
        return elapsedTime;
    }
}
public void reset(){
    elapsedTime = 0;
    isRunning = false;
}
}
```

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) Animation is typically best done in a custom painted `JPanel` rather that..

Comment: .. by moving a component. Use a Swing `Timer` to trigger the frames of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a couple of issues in your code:

1) You need to click your button twice to be able to kick start the animation. Rework your logic in actionPerformed code.

2) You are moving your label too far on first move. Use increment of 1 instead of 150.

3) Your animation is in event dispatch thread and it freezes the GUI. Move it into separate thread and update JLabel in event dispatch thread.

Here is working code:

```
    public static class animation {

private JFrame frame;

boolean isMoving = false;
int labelX = 0;
int labelY = 0;
int x, y;
private final JButton button = new JButton("Start");
JLabel lblO = new JLabel("O");
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                animation window = new animation();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public animation() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
     x = frame.getWidth();
     y = frame.getHeight();

    lblO.setBounds(0, 0, 15, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblO);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            button.setText("End");
            if(isMoving){

                new Thread( () -> movetheball() ).start();
            }
            else{
                isMoving = true;
            }
            }

    });
    button.setBounds(168, 219, 84, 31);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);



    }

public void movetheball(){
    StopWatch tim = new StopWatch();
    tim.start();
    while(isMoving){

        long time = tim.getElapsedtime();
        if(time>1){

            System.out.println("The Timer is Working");
            labelX+= 1;
            labelY += 1;

            EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> lblO.setBounds(labelX,labelY,15,15) );

            try {
                Thread.sleep( 100 );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    }


}
```